# What exactly is EditText.text returning?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        android:hint="Name"/>
```

In order to get the text of my `EditText` I need to add `toString()` to the end as seen below. But what exactly does `player_name.text` return?

```
val name: String = player_name.text.toString()
```

Comment: It returns an [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @Mike M., an `Editable` is returned:

> `getText`
>
> ```kotlin
> open fun getText(): Editable!
> ```
>
> *[EditText - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/EditText#gettext)*